# R plot, use line thickness to convey relative importance of information

Tags: r, plot

I have 5 lines that represent different trajectories that vary in their likelihood. I'd like to change the *relative* thickness of the lines to convey the information about their likelihood. The likelihoods add up to 100% and I'd like the thickness of the lines to reflect that, here is some dummy data

```
attempt<-matrix(0,ncol=6,nrow=5, dimnames=list(c("Intermediate A", 
    "Worst Case", "Intermediate B", "Best Case","Intermediate C"),
    c("likelihood",c(1:5))))

attempt[,1]<-c(0.2,0.10,0.30,0.25,0.15)
attempt[,2]<-c(rep(0,nrow(attempt)))
attempt[,3]<-c(0.1,0.2,0.15,0.06,0.15)
attempt[,4]<-c(0.2,0.4,0.2,0.10,0.3)
attempt[,5]<-c(0.3,0.6,0.25,0.18,0.4)
attempt[,6]<-c(0.4,0.8,0.3,0.21,0.5)

#want to plot these as lines that have varying thickness according to the
#likelihood in column 1

plot(0,0, xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="years", ylab="probability of 
extinction")
  lines(attempt[1,2:6], col="blue")
  lines(attempt[2,2:6], col="red")
  lines(attempt[3,2:6], col="brown")
  lines(attempt[4,2:6], col="green")
  lines(attempt[5,2:6], col="purple")
```

Most posts I've found point to overlapping lines (frequency) or varying the thickness of a single line over a different portion of the data, I want the reader to be able to judge which line is most likely (following the likelihood values in column 1) by the relative thickness of the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(attempt) %>%
  rownames_to_column()%>%
  gather(num, val, -likelihood, -rowname) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = num, y = val, group = rowname, color = rowname, size = likelihood))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-16 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

First, we convert to a dataframe, next we change the row names to a column, then we gather the data into long format, lastly we plot the data. In `aes` we can tell `ggplot` that we want the color to be based on the row names and the size of the line to be based on the likelihood.

Comment: thank you @AndS I really like the legend with the proportional sizes and likelihood information, I've converted data frames in that way to use ggplot before but without tidyverse, thanks for directing me to learn how to do that data manipulation!

Comment: the code no longer works on a slightly bigger dataset, my plot has improper breaks and I keep getting the warning message: using size for a discrete variable is not advised, I'm trying to quickly troubleshoot but am getting nowhere.

Comment: What do you mean improper breaks? Discrete variable warnings usually means that your size variable is not numeric

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(0,0, xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="years", ylab="probability of 
extinction")

lwd_mult <- 100

lines(attempt[1,2:6], col="blue", lwd=attempt[1, 1] * lwd_mult)
lines(attempt[2,2:6], col="red", lwd=attempt[2, 1] * lwd_mult)
lines(attempt[3,2:6], col="brown", lwd=attempt[3, 1] * lwd_mult)
lines(attempt[4,2:6], col="green", lwd=attempt[4, 1] * lwd_mult)
lines(attempt[5,2:6], col="purple", lwd=attempt[5, 1] * lwd_mult)
```

The `lwd` argument sets the relative thickness of the line and the `lwd_mult` parameter is used to visually scale the thickness.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: thanks @chrischrischris201 I may have made my dummy answer a bit too simple for my needs, would this work even if the values in column 1 didn't add up to 100? The reason would be that there is some likelihood that I didn't represent some scenarios outside of the 5 that are plotted (that's what I'll be modifying this for)

Comment: @KristenVoorhies The solution works for any positive likelihood value, you don't have to re-scale them so they add to one. Just adjust the `lwd_mult` value so it is visually to scale given the likelihood values.